# Image resize is not working for one image only

Tags: php, image

I used php `image magician library` to resize image, It is working fine for all images except one image, I doesn't know whats wrong with this image, does anyone have face this type of issue ?

[image]

Comment: We need to know what error messages you are getting, if any. Without this information I can only tell you that this image is a PNG file and you may want to check whether the other images are of a different file type, and whether type even matters for the library you are using.

Comment: You need to show us the code too...

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing such a problem then it must not be necessarily the fault of the image. Have you tried this image with any other software.

- Try it out with **any other** resizing software
- Try renaming this file as it might help.

The cause of such type of error might be that somebody might have alternated the **.png** code of this file by any text editor.